# Can you identify this 14-pin DIP resistor network?

Tags: resistors, identification

I'm trying to positively identify this resistor network. Has anyone encountered them before?

[image: An unknown resistor network in a 14-pin DIP package]

They were found on a backplane with 96-pin DIN 41612 connectors. It's not a VME bus — A/B/C1-3 are a big rail, possibly ground, and so is A/B/C32 (possibly Vcc). The bus pinout may be ad hoc. It's a relatively old device: early Nineties at the *absolute* latest, probably mid to late Eighties.

(Apologies for the graininess, it's an available light photo)

Comment: Produced in week 21 of 1983.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jonta says what you have there is a TTL Dual-Line Terminator / Pulse Squaring resistor network.  An example datasheet is [here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/31511/31511.pdf).  The internal circuitry is shown in the figure below:

[image: dual line res network]

Specifically you have a 330/470 Ohm version like the on [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MDP1405191AGE04/MDP330/470C-ND/1544603).

You have commented that you are reading between 60 and 70 ohms between the ground and common lines (pin 7 and 14).  This is correct!  If you study the schematic above, the equivalent resistance between those two pins would be twelve (330+470) Ohm resistors in parallel, or about 66 Ohms.

As the datasheet linked above states, these resistor networks are used for [TTL dual-line](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=slls080c) termination and pulse squaring.

Comment: Thanks. I keep underestimating just how much CMOS has changed my way of thinking. I can't imagine designing something that consumes this much power just to idle along. Not to mention the packages get *hot* (which is only to be expected... nowhere else for all that energy to go)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the top part is a part number and it looks a loot like the order number for instance [this](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf/13/40/134056/760-3-r22k.pdf) one.

If you look at the part number that would mean:

- 760 : 14 pins
- 5 : Dual terminator
- 330 : Value of R1
- 470 : Value of R2

Using the schematic and a ohm meter, you should be able to verify / rule out this.

Comment: Yup, that was my expectation. I'm reading 390Ω consistently, though, and there's what looks like a 60-70Ω resistance between pins 7 and 14, which is why I asked the question in the first place — I think the nets are b0rken somehow.